# Invalid type for ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

**Error :** java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for ParseObject: class org.json.JSONObject

I have moved parse server on **"centOS"** and also database from parse.com to **mangoDB**. I'm getting Above error when I make below request from my android app.

**Note** :  I'm using android parse sdk(v1.13.1)

I have tried to add jsonObject as arraylist using addAllUnique() method because I have to store jsonObject as datatype of "**array**" in parse database.

**Below i share my code :**

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

try {

    jsonObj.put("__type", "Pointer");
    jsonObj.put("className", className);
    jsonObj.put("objectId", objectId);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

user.addAllUnique("Keyword",Arrays.asList(jsonObj));

user.saveInBackground();
```

I have also tried user.addAll() method insted of addAllUnique() but it's also not working.

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Post ur error log

Comment: you may be mixing metaphors here.. the explicit use of pointer type is from the Rest api. If you are using the android SDK you can just create the classname as an object and wrap it in a named element and then add it to the class you want to point to it.

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thanks for your suggestion but I have to store jsonObject as **array** data-type in Parse database.  Before parse migration code is working fine for me. Please advice.

Comment: I am not clear with your question. Do you want to put an Array of Pointers?

Comment: @YeMinHtut yes exactly I want to store Array of Pointers. I have already store Array of Pointer in Parse DB using addAllUnique() method and it's working fine before Parse migration.

Comment: construct your collection of type jsonobject.   add the collection to an object of type jsonarray and then PUT that jsonarray object to another objtect then saveinbckground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this instead of JSON Object.

```
List<ParseObject> pointerList = new ArrayList<>();
pointerList.add(ParseObject.createWithoutData("YourClassName", "yourobjectId"));
pointerList.add(ParseObject.createWithoutData("YourClassName", "yourobjectId"));
...
user.addAllUnique("keyWord", pointerList);
user.saveInBackground();
```

Haven't tested the code yet. But technically, it should work.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I appriciate your response. I have tried this code to store Array of Pointer into Parse database but it stores like "[
        [
            {
           "objectId": "Pointer"
        },  
       {
           "objectId": "UserKeyword"
        },     
      {
            "objectId": "6mzDmu8iX1"
        }
        ]
]" 
but i required below format.

[
    {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "UserKeyword",
        "objectId": "DkfeM16GtA"
    },
    {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "UserKeyword",
        "objectId": "lkcnla8icJ"
    }
]

Comment: It's because of `Arrays.asList(pointerList)`. I've edited my answer. Try again. @Dinesh

Comment: Delete the wrong data in your column before you test it.